# None en un for, cuando imprimo

Tags: python

Tengo esta situación:

```
    def listarDepartamentos(li):
        print ('LOS DEPARTAMENTOS CARGADOS SON:')
        for x in li:
            print(x.muestrarOficina())
            print (x.getNumOfis()

    def muestrarOficina(self):
        print ('LA INFO:',self.numOficina,'', self.nombreOficina,'',self.cantEmpleados)
```

y la salida es:

```
EL NUMERO DE OFICINA ES:  22
None
LA INFO:  33 # CCC # 333
None
EL NUMERO DE OFICINA ES:  33
None
```

¿Saben por qué muestra en la salida este NONE?
Es un simple `for`.
Es un código simple pero no sé por qué hace esto.

Comment: ¿Puedes adjuntar también la definición `getNumOfis`?? De todos modos, ¿no te falta cerrar ahí un paréntesis? Del modo `print (x.getNumOfis()` **)**  <<- Ese paréntesis me refiero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `muestrarOficina()` que has escrito **no devuelve resultados**, sino que los imprime.

Cuando desde la otra función haces `print(x.muestrarOficina())` estás pidiendo a Python que imprima lo que `muestrarOficina()` devuelve. Ya que no devuelve nada, Python imprimirá `None`.

Las posibles soluciones a esto serían:

1. O bien no imprimir el resultado devuelto (puesto que en realidad no devuelve nada)
2. O bien Hacer que la función `muestrarOficina()` sí que devuelva algo en lugar de imprimirlo.

Generalmente se prefiere la opción 2, puesto que de ese modo la función `muestraOficina()` sería más genérica y más útil en otros contextos (por ejemplo, si quieres que esa información vaya a fichero en vez de a pantalla).

### Codigo para la solución 1

```
    def listarDepartamentos(li):
        print ('LOS DEPARTAMENTOS CARGADOS SON:')
        for x in li:
            x.muestrarOficina()  # quitamos los print que había aqui
            x.getNumOfis()

    def muestrarOficina(self):
        print ('LA INFO:',self.numOficina,'', self.nombreOficina,'',self.cantEmpleados)
```

### Código para la solución 2

```
    def listarDepartamentos(li):
        print ('LOS DEPARTAMENTOS CARGADOS SON:')
        for x in li:
            print(x.muestrarOficina())  # Se mantienen estos print
            print(x.getNumOfis())

    def muestrarOficina(self):
        # Pero ahora esta función no imprime nada, sino que retorna la cadena
        return f'LA INFO: {self.numOficina} {self.nombreOficina} {self.cantEmpleados}"

    # Y análogamente para la función getNumOfis()
```

Observa cómo he usado una f-string para concatenar en una sola cadena lo que antes imprimías desde `muestraOficina()`

Comment: S'i.  No es que era un problema.  Es que no entendia el None y no encontre algo que me aclare la duda. @abulafia.  Como estoy probando algunas muchas cosas lo enfoque como un return y es cierto, es un print. Muchas Gracias, por tu tiempo y tus comentarios.